# What algorithm's can be used to fill an irregular 3D object?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 3d

I have an irregular polygon in 3D, and have coordinates of points present on the boundary of the polygon. Assume that I have placed cubes of some size on all such points present on the boundary. With the help of these cubes I can search for all 3D objects which intersect with my polygon. Now in order search for all objects which are either inside or outside my polygon I need to populate the 3D polygon with such cubes.

Can anyone help on how can I fill in my 3D polygon with all such cubes.

Comment: AFAIK, this is called Marching cubes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to fill the polyhedron (this is the name of a 3d polygon), instead you could calculate its hull, which might be a Convex Hull or concave hull depending on your intent.